# How to hide an Objective C declaration from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working on a library written in Objective-C. I want to have some methods available to callers written in Swift, and not available to callers written in Objective-C.

Going in the other direction, you can control Swift visibility in Objective-C with the `@objc` and `@nonobjc` attributes. Are there equivalents to make some Objective-C methods Swift-only or Objective-C-only?

Would I have to maintain a separate header? And if so, is there any way I could require Swift users to import `Library-Swift.h` in their bridging headers instead of `Library.h`?

Comment: Why you want to hide ObjC method from ObjC code?

Comment: I want to add methods that make life easier for Swift (with error handling), without breaking backward-compatibility for existing Objective-C consumers.

Comment: There MAY be some macro variable that can be used in the header file to bypass sections based on whether you're compiling Objective-C or Swift.  I've never looked to see if this is possible.

Comment: Why adding new method will break backward-compatibility?

Comment: @BryanChen I'm adding an `error` argument to the initializers for the class, and don't want to break every place where existing Objective-C code doesn't check it. I'm okay with that for Swift, as the error handling is new and everyone will be updating their code for it already

Comment: I think you should add the new method and depreciate the old one. People can still use the old one but they will see a warning tell them to use the safer method.

Comment: @BryanChen That wasn't exactly what I had in mind, but it's a good suggestion, and that's what I've implemented unless/until I find out there's a clean way to separate the two from the Objective-C side.

Comment: You can use `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("")` to hide an ObjC method from Swift. `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` also hides it but it's not very semantic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need separate headers,one for swift and one for objc(for the class).And for swift you could make a header for the whole framework(just for swift,and where you put the swift header for that class),and who wants to use your framework in swift include that header into their bridging header.